# Adding an Image Slider using ViewFlipper, but the App stops on startup

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using this code to make an Image Slider, but the Application stops on startup. Help !!
You might suggest any other way to make an Image Slider in a Fragment also.
This is my java code.

gallery.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class gallery extends Fragment{

View myView;
Animation fade_in, fade_out;
ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery, container, false);

    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) myView.findViewById(R.id.backvf);

    fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
    fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out);

    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(fade_in);
    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(fade_out);
    viewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
    viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000);
    viewFlipper.startFlipping();

    return myView;
    }
}
```

This is my XML file.

activity_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.harshit.sangeetasventure.gallery">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/backvf"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/slide1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/slide2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/slide3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/slide4" />
    </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

And these are the fade_in.xml and fade_out.xml in the @res/amin.

fade_in & fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" />
</set>
```

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: share the log .

Comment: It shows a RunTime error on this line:

myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery, container, false);

Comment: As i Run the App, the App stops,, & in the logcat, error is shown on the line

Comment: Please note that I am making An app with a Navigation Drawer in it, and "Gallery" is a tab in it. All my other tabs are running fine, but when i click "gallery" after this code, the app stops. And in the logs, it shows a RunTime error on this line:
myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery, container, false);